# Upgrade Issue: 17.10 to 18.04: Failure with Internet or network error

Tags: networking, upgrade, updates, 17.10, repository

I have made several attempts to upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 and yet both at the cache repository level and upgrade installation - the same failure is experienced blaming the internet connection. I have attempted both a wireless and wire connect to both the main server and the server in the US. The specific error is not compatible to a network failure in my opinion.

```
E:The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security Release' no longer has a Release file., 
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' no longer has a Release file., 
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
```

See comments please
Updated 5/30/18

Comment: could you add to your post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` ... formatted with the button{}

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Your internet connection and the package archive server appear to be fine. Are you sure you're on Ubuntu 17.10 Artful Aardvark and not the old and unsupported Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety Yak? Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lsb_release -a` and `apt-cache policy ubuntu-minimal` and the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`? Thanks.

Comment: ubuntu-minimal:
  Installed: 1.404.1
  Candidate: 1.404.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.404.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.404 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages

Comment: No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 17.10
Release: 17.10
Codename: artful

Comment: Too long... So it needs to be cleaned as i guessed. ... You can use the ubuntu paste bin : https://paste.ubuntu.com/.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TdM62YY6hW/